# Launch a specific tab and then specific section and cell index from UITableView Programmatically

Tags: iphone, uitableview, indexing, uitabbarcontroller, appdelegate

I used to use like `tabBarController.selectedIndex = 3` if I want to change the active tab at launch for conditional reason like if I get a push notification and launch that specific view.

but now the view I want to show is for example the 3rd tab and inside that view (which is a `UITableView`) I want to select specific section and cell index.

If I know this index values a head of time can I programmatically lunch this view?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to scroll a UITableView to a certain cell/position?

Comment: not scroll first launch specific tap by `tabBarController.selectedIndex = x` then call `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` on that view

Answer (score 0):

To select a cell, you'll need:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad:(BOOL)animated {
    // assuming you had the table view wired to IBOutlet myTableView
    // and that you wanted to select the first item in the first section
    [myTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:0];
}
```